# Integrating adwhirl with Buzztouch 1.4 on Android,crashes phone

Tags: android, adwhirl, buzztouch

I am trying to add Adwhirl to a Buzztouch app on Android but it crashes the phone.  Admob on its own is OK.

The Adwhirl code has been added to the custom text page code in Buzztouch 1.4.
I have an app set up in the Adwhirl control panel that uses Admob.

The Admob and Adwhirl SDKs are included in the `libs` folder and linked to the build path

**Manifest extract**

```
     <!-- starting activity -->
    <activity android:name=".Act_Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:value="8a1d###cf6482407ba52947923949d714"
    android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name=".Screen_CustomText" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"            
             android:screenOrientation="sensor" 
             android:configChanges="orientation">
        <meta-data android:value="8a1d92cf64###ba52947923949d714" 
   android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>
    </activity>
```

**Main activity extract**

```
//onCreate
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_customtext);
    AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("online games gaming");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("bb54de");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);
    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout)findViewById(R.id.adwhirl_layout);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int diWidth = 320;
    int diHeight = 52;
    int density = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;      
    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int)(diWidth * density));
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int)(diHeight * density));
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    textView.setText("Below AdWhirlLayout");
    LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    layout2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layout2.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);
    layout2.addView(textView, layoutParams);
    layout2.invalidate();
```

**layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/global_title_dark" />
 <!-- Layout for admob -->
 <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout                        
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/myContent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Layout for adwhirl -->     
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout_main"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.adwhirl"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">
<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
            android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

**Error log extract, the error starts at "stored config data not present"**

```
06-03 09:39:06.072: I/AdWhirl SDK(5954): Finished creating adWhirlManager
06-03 09:39:06.072: D/AdWhirl SDK(5954): Prefs{null}: {"config": "[]
06-03 09:39:06.072: D/AdWhirl SDK(5954): ", "timestamp": 1338665057125}
06-03 09:39:06.072: D/AndroidRuntime(5954): Shutting down VM
06-03 09:39:06.072: I/AdWhirl SDK(5954): Stored config info not present or expired, 
fetching     fresh data**
06-03 09:39:06.072: W/dalvikvm(5954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0x4027a5a0)
06-03 09:39:06.082: E/AndroidRuntime(5954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 09:39:06.082: E/AndroidRuntime(5954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.v1_4.eightiespopquiz.com/
com.v1_4.eightiespopquiz.com.Screen_CustomText}:  
java.lang.ClassCastException:              
android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be setting your content view with

`setContentView(R.layout.screen_customtext);`

to a layout id that doesn't exist.  That is, `R.layout.screen_customtext` doesn't seem to be defined in your layout xml.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.screen_customtext);points to the layout file for this activity which is correct and present.Thanks.